# ZF2 The model class

Tags: model, zend-framework2, getter-setter

In some ZF2 examples I noticed two different kind of Model class notations, one using getters/setters or one using the arrayExchange function. I am wondering what the differences are and what/when to use. I noticed the getters and setters won't work for a normal ResultSet but do work when we Hydrate.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a difference in the sense that you mean. ZF2 supports a few different ways of hydrating an object (see the docs for [Zend\Stdlib\Hydrate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html)). ArraySerializable uses the array exchange function, ClassMethods will call your getters and setters. As long as your model implements the hydrator interface, ZF2 will hydrate it correctly. Which one you pick is largely down to personal preference.